ASP.NET Core 8.0 CORS middleware not sent via OPTIONS
I have created a RESTFUL API using ASP.NET Core 8.0 with Entity Framework, and hosted it on AWS's Elastic Beanstalk (with https routing). Since the frontend is hosted on Netlify, it sends the OPTIONS preflight requests before any other method to get the CORS policy. But for some reason my API does not return any CORS policies with the requests. Furthermore, it blocks any OPTIONS methods with 405 Method Not Allowed. Even after explicitly adding the HttpOptions requests that return the Ok() result, the CORS rules are still not sent by the server.
My CORS policies are setup like this in the Program.cs file:
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
  options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigins", builder =>
  {
    string[] allowedOrigins = new string[]
    {
        "https://my-website.netlify.app",
        "http://localhost:3000",
        "https://localhost:3000",
        "http://localhost:4000",
        "https://localhost:4000"
    };

    builder.WithOrigins(allowedOrigins)
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader()
           .AllowCredentials();
  });
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigins");

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
  app.UseSwagger();
  app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
 app.UseHttpsRedirection(); // Optional
}

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

I have also created a headers.toml file in the root of the repository of my React frontend which looks like this:
/* 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://my-website.netlify.app
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true


To confirm, does your CORS policy work correctly when running locally? Can you provide any developer console output?

I'm afraid it worked well locally.

Firstly, we might add a specific endpoint for option request. `[HttpOptions][Route("{*any}")]public IActionResult HandlePreflightRequests(){return Ok();}`` If it doesn't work, we do need to consider whether there's a restrict for the option request. Pls check whether there's any reverse proxy/gateway/load balancer on your server then check whether there's a rule which stopping the option request.

@Peppermintology hey, sorry for the late response. When navigating to Chrome Console > Network > signin(the method we invoke in the frontend), the Response headers are completely empty. Is it because the sign in method failed or is it empty because of a failed CORS setup in the backend? There 2 signin methods showing up in the Network tab, 1 red and 1 white. The white one has the following Response Headers:
Request URL: https://backend.com | Request Method: OPTIONS | Status Code: 204 No Content | Remote Address: (IP address) | Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin | 

does your CORS policy work correctly when running locally?

@TinyWang When running my frontend locally on Localhost:4000 via npm start, the results are the same. The way I am making these API calls are directly in page files. For example, a POST method has a dedicated function in Home.js. Do I need to setup something for that to work? It used to work without an SSL certificate or a Load Balancer. Furthermore, all methods work correctly using POSTMAN, so the issue is probably coming from the browser side

CORS issue is throw by browser when the browser is detecting a request is sending to a cross-orgin domain, so that you wont get CORS issue when using postman to call the API. To solve the CORS issue, we need to do configuration in the API side, so that my question about "does your CORS policy work correctly when running locally" is trying to confirm whether your client(no matter the client is running locally or not) could call the API succeussfully when the API is hosting locally... And I noticed you mentioned It used to work without an SSL certificate or a Load Balancer. I'm afraid it's due

it's due to the load balancer.... Could u pls try to remove the load balancer temporarily just for test purpose?

@TinyWang yes, it works after removing the load balancer from my EC2 instance. I have configured the Load Balancer to have an SSL certificate by purchasing a domain on Namecheap, creating a route in Route53, assigning 4 DNS addresses it gave me to my domain, then issued an SSL certificate in Amazon Certificate Manager. Then I created an HTTPS listener on my Load Balancer and gave it that certificate. The problem is, it doesn't work on Netlify frontend(which is also HTTPS) and on localhost(which is HTTP). Do I need some sort of CORS setup on the frontend part?

@Roomba Hi, if we have load balanor we might need to set CORS related configuration in load balanor instead of the client APP, we don't need to do any changes in the client app when we got CORS error. Let's assume we are using Nginx as the load balanor, then we might search for "Nginx how to set CORS policy" If you are using AWS builtin service, then you might search for how to set cors policy for this service.
